# Security deposit received back

Tags: security, deposits

Do security deposit grow interest and and what if u paid all the repairs they cannot keep your deposit they can’t keep your deposit for nothing if u paid for all the repairs. And u have texts message that everything paid in full

Comment: The laws regarding security deposits are based on the location of the property. Please specify the country, and if the United States please specify the state.

Comment: It's incredibly difficult to get your security deposit back.  They always just say "oh this is damaged" and keep all or most of your money.  No, no interest.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, no, security deposits do not earn interest. Where my rentals are, we have to pass the bond on to a government agency, who then send it back to the renter once we release it.

You don't say where you are, so I can't advise you whether to go to your local equivalent of the tenancy disputes tribunal or small claims court.